# Implementation of chart with MVP

Tags: c#, mvp, mschart

I am new to using MVP to structure my projects, but have a current project where I want to apply it.

I have a back end which parses log files to generate a `DataTable` of data. This is then returned to the form for displaying in a `DataGridView`. The form then controls another backend to plot the data as a chart, which is returned for display.

My question is this: when creating the chart, what should be done in the view/presenter?

I.e. should the presenter create the chart and send it to the view as a `Chart` object to be added to the panel and displayed? Or should the presenter tell the view "create new chart", "add data point", "rename x axis", etc.. which would lead to a huge interface to cover everything required..

Are there any examples for using MVP in this sort of "slightly more complicated than just a list and a button" example?

Comment: My understanding of MVP is that, the Presenter takes the responsibility of interpreting whats coming to/from the view, then the view will display what coming from the presenter. Therefore, I support your idea of the Presenter creating the Chart and send it to the View for display.

Comment: Well this greatly simplifies the interface, but it almost seems like this is passing a GUI control - which seems wrong..

Comment: I'm going to give you a small code snippet, which you can play with and see if it helps in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
   public class YourModel 
   { 
      public Chart GenerateChart()
      {
         Chart chart = new Chart();
        //place code to set up the chat, i.e. Axis, BackColors...etc
      }
   }

   public class YourPresenter
   {
     IView _view;
     public YourPresenter(IView view)
     {
         _view = view;
     }

     public void GetChart()
     {
        YourModel model = new YourModel();
        _view.ChartControl = model.GenerateChart();
     }
   }

   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page,IView 
   {
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     }
     protected void ButtonResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        YourPresenter presenter = new YourPresenter(this);
        presenter.GetChart();
     }

     public Chart ChartControl
     {
        get{return "a placeHolder where your chart is displayed";}
        set{"a placceHolder where your chart will be displayed" = value;}
     }
   }
   public interface IView
   {
     Chart ChartControl { get; set;}
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. So, then if I can drag a data series to the other Y axis, how would you handle that? Would you regenerate the whole chart using the model and then replace it in the view? It seems a shame to have to redo so much processing to make a minor modification.